# How to track the history of Automatic builds in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have ticked the Project -> Build automatically option in my elcipse(Juno Service Release 2).
Is there a way to see the history of these Automatic  builds.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What do you expect to see in this history? I can't image any benefit of this. An automatic build is triggered after you have changed a source file.

Comment: I wanted to see whether a build is triggered. Sometimes even after i changed a source file a build is not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the auto-build requests by running Eclipse with the `-debug` option and a custom debug file. The debug file would contain:

```
org.eclipse.core.resources/debug=true 
org.eclipse.core.resources/build/needbuild=true
```

Specify `-debug path-to-debug-options-file` on the Eclipse start command.

Note: There are a lot!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. You mean to say that i need to create a file with the mentioned two entries and give the location of that file  to as a parameter to eclipse start command with -debug option right ?Did it like as you mentioned and in the console which prompts when eclipse starts shows that file is loaded with debug options. but nothing is written to the file. Anything i missed ?